# How to split a long coroutine without using await?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a coroutine that is getting too big and I'd like to split it for readability.

```
async def handle_message(self, message):
    message_type = message.get('type')

    if message_type == 'broadcast':
        ...
        for n in self._neighbors:
            await self.send_message(n, message)

    elif message_type == 'graph':
        ...
```

I'd like to extract the portion which handles broadcast messages into a private method like this:

```
async def handle_message(self, message):
    message_type = message.get('type')
    ...

    if message_type = 'broadcast':
        await self._handle_broadcast(message)
    elif message_type = 'graph':
        ...
```

The problem is that this changes the behavior of the code, since the `_handle_broadcast` part is a coroutine and its execution might be delayed since I call it with `await`.

What is the way to ensure that the coroutine runs immediately and isn't delayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: split the coroutine exactly like you started, by using `await`.

> The problem is that this changes the behavior of the code, since the `_handle_broadcast` part is a coroutine and its execution might be delayed since I call it with `await`.

For better or worse, this premise is false. When given a coroutine, `await` immediately starts executing it without an intermediate delay. It is only **if** that coroutine calls something that causes it to suspend (such as `asyncio.sleep` or a network read that doesn't have data yet) that your coroutine gets suspended along with it - which is precisely what you would get had the code stayed inline.

In that sense `await <some coroutine>` works like the coroutine equivalent of a regular function call, allowing precisely the kind of non-semantics-changing refactoring that you need. This can be demonstrated with an example:

```
import asyncio

async def heartbeat():
    while True:
        print('tick')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def noop():
    pass

async def coro():
    # despite "await", this blocks the event loop!
    while True:
        await noop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(heartbeat())
loop.create_task(coro())
loop.run_forever()
```

The above code blocks the event loop - even though `coro` does nothing except `await` in a loop. So `await` is not a guarantee of yielding to the event loop, the coroutine has to do it with other means. (This behavior can also be a source of [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50722571/1600898).)

In the above case, one can get the event loop "un-stuck" by inserting an `await asyncio.sleep(0)`. But that kind of thing should never be needed in production asyncio code, where the program should be structured so that each coroutine does comparatively little work, and then uses `await` to obtain more data.

Comment: Wow, so I had a misunderstanding of how `await` worked. This and the link you provided actually explain a lot about issues I've been having on this same project earlier, which uses `asyncio.open_connection` as well. Thanks!

Comment: @JacqueGoupil To further understand how `await` and the event loop work, you can also take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4). It explains things in terms of generators which most Python programmers are already familiar with, but that also happens to be exactly how `await` works behind the scenes.

Comment: I should have watched this video months ago.